# Discord.py Handeling multiple sessions with multiple users

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

so I made several very simple discord bots with the on_message approach.My question would be how can I make the bot hold several conversations at the same time. For example: Lets say I have a bot that can handle reports on my discord server. You initiate the conversation with "-somecommand" and than the bot DM's you with several questions about the issue you want to report. It goes question -- waits for answer -- question2 --and so on and so on. Problem is that while this conversation goes on nobody can initiate another "report session" with the bot. I have tried using threads,asyncio both were headaches and kinda just gave up with it.So overall my question would be the following : How can I make the bot multitask ?
My idea of the solution is that I put the "report" function on another process/thread(whatever we call it) and I just keep on creating these threads/processes(whatever) for as many people that I need. I dont know wether this is the most optimal or best approach and if there is a better approach please do tell.

EDIT1:

So, when I encountered this problem I was developing a bot that would gather 10 players valorant rank and make teams based on their respective elo.The 10 people would be in the same voice channel. Kinda like a matchmaking bot. I had to make this works for last friday so I worked around the problem and settled for "not multitasking" solution.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.content == "--matchmake":
        channel_id = message.author.voice.channel.id
        voice = message.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
        members = voice.members
```

This part here just gathers all the members who are in the voice channel of the message creator.

```
        for member in members:
             await member.send("Hey please respond with your valorant rank")
```

So, here I private message everyone who is in the room.

```
        while len(players_list) < 10:
             response = await client.wait_for("message")
             if correct_input(response.content):
             #if the player is already in the players list
             #and if the response is correct, I add the player to the list 
             #and tell him he is added
             await member.send("You have successfully joined!")
```

And this here is what causes me the problem because if 2 player respond at the exact same time, only 1 of their responses will be checked and responded to, the other person will be ignored while the message format checking is going on

```
    def correct_input(self,mssg):

    try:
        mssg = mssg.split()
        # print(mssg)
        div = [mssg[0][:-1], int(mssg[0][-1])]
        if len(div[0]) < 2:
            return False
        # print(div)
        ranks = ["iron", "bronze", "silver", "gold", "platinum", "diamond", "immortal"]

        for elo in ranks:
            if div[0].lower() in elo:
                #print(div)
                return True

        return False
    except(ValueError, TypeError):
        return False
```

Here is the correct_input function which basiclly just checks if the input split up is correct and can be translated to elo numbers if not it returns false and the bot await player.send("Wrong Input")

Comment: Welcome to SO! The `async-await` framework is designed to support your exact requirements without needing any multithreading etc. It sounds like some part of your code is blocking and prevents new commands from being handled. Consider editing your question to include the relevant pars of your code and we should be able to help you out

Comment: @Lukas Thaler I have updated the post

Comment: @LukasThaler ...

Comment: You correctly identified the culprit: there is a period of time in each iteration of your while loop where your bot is not listening for messages (also, right now, any message will trigger the event, you might want to consider adding a check to ensure only people from the voice chat trigger it). This might actually require some more advanced setup to consistently catch all messages, I'll have to think about the best way for this

Comment: So I am guessing I either make the input checker an await function or run that single function on a different thread/process. If thats the case making it an await function seems way easier ? @LukasThaler

Comment: Just making the check asynchronous won't fix the issue, sadly. Your bot is only listening for messages in the first line of the while loop. While all the other processing is taking place, it won't count any responses towards this command. I guess making a `--respondmatchmake` command and a shared variable holding all participants (voice chat members) will be the easiest way

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that aswell but I wanted to make it so the response doesnt need to inclued a command. I cant really explain why I wanted this approach but I guess i cant get around it. Thank you for the answers and the help. @LukasThaler